# Invalid csrf token due to session id regenerate

Tags: php, ajax, session, csrf-token

I have just sent you a code. Essentially, what I am attempting to achieve is to regenerate the session ID to prevent session attacks and session hijacking. I accomplish this by using session regeneration. However, I encounter an issue when using CRSF tokens. Specifically, when I send a request to my controller without loading the page, it returns as invalid. This occurs because the CRSF token updates after the session ID is regenerated, but the input field does not get updated accordingly.

I am seeking guidance on how to handle this situation. One approach I considered is updating the session ID by sending the CRSF token through the controller back to the rejection point and updating the input field. However, placing this process inside the valid condition for the CRSF token does not seem to work. Can you provide guidance on how to address this issue?

`<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" class="csrf_token" value="' . CSRFHelper::generateCsrfToken() . '">`

this is my sesssion.php code

```
<?php

namespace App\Core\Session;

class SessionManager
{
    public static function startSecureSession()
    {
        // Set session cookie attributes for security
        session_set_cookie_params([
            'lifetime' => 3600, // Session timeout in seconds (adjust as needed)
            'path' => '/',
            'domain' => 'localhost',
            'secure' => true,    // Send cookies only over HTTPS
            'httponly' => true   // Prevent JavaScript access to cookies
        ]);

        // Start a secure session after setting cookie parameters
        session_start();

        // Regenerate the session ID to prevent session fixation
        self::regenerateSessionId();
    }

    public static function regenerateSessionId()
    {
        // Regenerate the session ID to prevent session fixation
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
```

This is my init.php code

```
<?php
require_once 'app\core\session\session.php';
require_once 'app\core\config\config.php';
require_once 'app\core\controller\controller.php';
require_once 'app\core\database\database.php';
require_once 'app\core\route\app.php';
require_once 'app\core\csrf\CSRFHelper.php';
use App\Core\Session\SessionManager;
SessionManager::startSecureSession();

?>
```

this is index.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'app/init.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Core\Route\App;
$app = new App();
?>
```

this is csrf token page

```
<?php
namespace App\Core\Csrf;
class CSRFHelper {
    public static function generateCsrfToken() {
        // Check if a CSRF token already exists in the session
        if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
            // If not, generate a new one
            $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
        }
        return $_SESSION['csrf_token'];
    }

    public static function verifyCsrfToken($token) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) && hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf_token'], $token)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
   
?>
```

this is ajax

```
  $(document).on("click", "#sinCon", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submit
    // Get the input value
    var csrf_token = $(".csrf_token").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var error = false;

    // Regex patterns for email and phone number
    var emailRegex = /^([\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var phoneRegex = /^([0-9]{3}[- .]?){2}[0-9]{4}$/;

    if (password === "") {
      $("#password").next(".error").text("Password is required").show();
      error = true;
    } else if (password.length < 8) {
      $("#password")
        .next(".error")
        .text("Password should be at least 8 characters")
        .show();
      error = true;
    } else {
      $("#password").next(".error").hide();
    }

    if (email === "") {
      $("#email")
        .next(".error")
        .text("Enter your email or mobile phone number")
        .show();
      error = true;
    } else if (emailRegex.test(email) || phoneRegex.test(email)) {
    // Send the data via AJAX
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: BASEURL + "signin/login", // Replace with the URL of your PHP script that inserts data
      data: { csrf_token: csrf_token, email: email, password: password },
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#sinCon").html(
          '<div class="spinner-border text-light s_eC87zS" role="status"></div>'
        );
        $("#sinCon").addClass("a_uB1q1E");
        $("#sinCon").prop("disabled", true);
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#sinCon").removeClass("a_uB1q1E");
        $("#sinCon").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#sinCon").html("Continue");

        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data.success === "verified") {
          // Handle success response
          window.location.href = BASEURL;
          // console.log(data); // Log the response to the console
        } else if (data.error) {
          $(".e_zEZTIS").html('<p id="error_message">' + data.error + "</p>");
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle error response
        //console.log(xhr.responseText); // Log the error message to the console
        $(".e_zEZTIS").html('<p id="error_message">' + error + "</p>"); // Display the error message to the user
      },
    });
    } else {
      // Invalid input
      // Show an error message or do something else
      $("#email").next(".error").text("Invalid Credential").show();
      error = true;
    }
  });
```

this is controller

```
    //<<>>[[ Login Data Passing To model ]]<<>>/
    public function login()
    {
        // Verify the CSRF token
        if (isset($_POST['csrf_token']) && CSRFHelper::verifyCsrfToken($_POST['csrf_token'])) {
            $signin = new User();
            $username = trim($_POST["email"]);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);
            $result = $signin->login($username, $password);

            if ($result) {
                echo json_encode(["success" => $_SESSION['success']]);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(["error" => $_SESSION['error']]);
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(["success" => false, "error" => "Invalid CSRF token"]);
        }
    }
```